# Loading JSON file in BigQuery using Google BigQuery Client API

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Is there a way to load a JSON file from local file system to BigQuery using Google BigQuery Client API?

All the options I found are:

1- Streaming the records one by one.

2- Loading JSON data from GCS.

3- Using raw POST requests to load the JSON (i.e. not through Google Client API).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming from the python tag that you want to do this from python. There is a load example [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch06/load_resumable.py) that loads data from a local file (it uses CSV, but it is easy to adapt it to JSON... there is another json example in the same directory).

The basic flow is:

```
# Load configuration with the destination specified.
load_config = {
  'destinationTable': {
    'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
    'datasetId': DATASET_ID,
    'tableId': TABLE_ID
  }
}

load_config['schema'] = {
  'fields': [
    {'name':'string_f', 'type':'STRING'},
    {'name':'boolean_f', 'type':'BOOLEAN'},
    {'name':'integer_f', 'type':'INTEGER'},
    {'name':'float_f', 'type':'FLOAT'},
    {'name':'timestamp_f', 'type':'TIMESTAMP'}
  ]
}
load_config['sourceFormat'] = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'

# This tells it to perform a resumable upload of a local file
# called 'foo.json' 
upload = MediaFileUpload('foo.json',
                         mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                         # This enables resumable uploads.
                         resumable=True)

start = time.time()
job_id = 'job_%d' % start
# Create the job.
result = jobs.insert(
  projectId=project_id,
  body={
    'jobReference': {
      'jobId': job_id
    },
    'configuration': {
      'load': load
    }
  },
  media_body=upload).execute()

 # Then you'd also want to wait for the result and check the status. (check out
 # the example at the link for more info).
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! Missed the media_body parameter in the doc. It is pretty far down after all the JSON config options for body :)

Comment: If you have the json object (100000 json) it will be imported in memory, What is the best option to upload data if I dismiss streaming, loading JSON data from GCS or using raw POST requests?