# Unresolved reference 'MediaFileUpload'

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use the Google driveApi in python while I get this error, I installed all the necessary dependecies, but I am still getting this problem for Unresolved reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/dandalo/GoogleDriveAPI.py", line 2, in 
   <module>
    class UploadToGoogleDrive:
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/dandalo/GoogleDriveAPI.py", line 20, in 
UploadToGoogleDrive
    media = googleapiclient.MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
AttributeError: module 'googleapiclient' has no attribute 'MediaFileUpload'
```

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
class UploadToGoogleDrive:

from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools


# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a local CSV to google big query using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196022/how-to-upload-a-local-csv-to-google-big-query-using-python)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to import MediaFileUpload from `googleapiclient`.

[`MediaFileUpload`](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload-class.html) comes from the http module in `googleapiclient`

Try this instead 
`media = googleapiclient.http.MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg')`

Answer (score 2):

just add this to your code

```
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
```

Comment: it should be `from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload`